# give image a border if radio button is checked

Tags: html, css

I want to give an image a border if a radio button is checked.

This is the HTML syntax:

```
<div class="frm_radio">
  <label for="field_n9r1a2-0">
    <input type="radio" name="x" id="t" value="Betreuung">
    Betreuung 
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/unterichten_betreuen.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
```

I try it with CSS selector `:checked` but it doesn't work.

```
input[type=radio]:checked img {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Can somebody explain how I can solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a `~` (sibling) operator:

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ img {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Without the `~` it treats as `radio` button being the parent of `img`. If you didn't have any text, I would have suggested `+`.

```css
input[type=radio]:checked ~ img {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="frm_radio">
  <label for="field_n9r1a2-0">
    <input type="radio" name="x" id="t" value="Betreuung">
    Betreuung 
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/unterichten_betreuen.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @cgee Thanks buddy. That would encourage us a lot. `:)`